# Is saving a user identity token as a key, a secure approach using expo-secure-store?

Tags: react-native, security, expo, android-keystore

I have a react-native app - users can log in and out with `firebase` authentication, but `expo-secure-store` is accessible app-wide, so users could potentially access data from other users stored in `secure-store` who logged in on the same device.

I want to save and retrieve specific user data from `secure-store`, and my solution to the above is to save each user identity token as the key, with the value containing its respective data. Is this a secure approach?  Does `expo-secure-store` encrypt the key *and* values or just the values?

My main gripe with this approach is that given each user can only have one key-value pair, data store for each user would be limited to the max size of 2048 bytes, which isn't a whole lot. Other solutions welcome :)